# I need to toggle between bitly links and posts in a window

Tags: javascript, html

When I load my window, this code automatically fires:

```
<script>
  var shareSettings = {
    linksOnly: true 
  }
</script>
```

But when I try to run the same code with a function, from a button, it doesn't work.

```
<a href="#" class="btn" onClick="linksOn();return false;">Links Only</a>

<script>
  function linksOn() {
    var shareSettings = { 
      linksOnly: true 
    }
  }
</script>
```

Can't see why it won't work with a button.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaybanjade/zvoeasgh/

Comment: So the script I am trying to run is at http://apdiagnostic.market-online.net/share-again.  When the page loads, the default value of 'linksOnly' is set to 'false'.  I need to have a button that when clicked, changes that value to 'true' - without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should declare `shareSettings` variable beforehand

```
<a href="#" class="btn" onClick="linksOn();return false;">Links Only</a>

<script>
var shareSettings = { linksOnly: false };

function linksOn() {
   shareSettings = { linksOnly: true }
}
</script>
```